# Is this regular expression possible?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm still pretty new to regexes. Is what I want possible to do normally, or do I have to do some sort of trickery?

I want to get everything between every set of curly brackets that isn't between a  set of curly brackets. Here's what I mean.

```
{ This is {a} test }  { this {is a{ also a } } } test }
```

I'd like a regex to return

```
['This is {a} test', 'this {is a{ also a } } } test' ]
```

Is this possible?

**Edit:**

I'm doing this in Javascript. The reason I need this is I'm getting a string that looks like this:

```
{ user entered value 1} {user entered value 2 }.....
```

I need to get all the user values. I just need to watch out for the case when a user enters a '}' and I get a string like this

{ this is {a} problem } { this {{ would }}}} be too }

**Edit 2**

I've decided just to redesign how I'm doing things. I don't need this regex anymore, but thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: If by "regex" you genuinely mean "regular expression", then -- no, this requires a context-free grammar. If by "regex" you mean something language-specific (such as Perl regexes, Java regexes, etc.), then you'll need to indicate the language. Some of them have special features for this, some of them don't.

Comment: @Juhana A nice challange. Mark states below that it is not possible, so please be polite and show how to do this. ...Meanwhile comments and answers have changed...

Comment: (Though actually, your example is strange, in that your curly brackets don't match up: you have more of `}` than of `{`. How do you identify a "set" of curly brackets?)

Comment: @barts It was more a throwaway gag than a serious response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible using standard regular expressions.

To do this you would have to count the nesting level of the curly brackets, but counting arbitrary nesting is not possible with a regular expression. If you are willing to restrict to a maximum of *n* nested levels, then yes it can be done.

Comment: Is there a better approach to my problem then? I'm going to be getting a string that looks like this

' { user entered value2 } {user entered value2} {user entered value 3}....

I'm trying to get all the user values. The values could be anything though, and may include ['s, or anything.

Comment: @edsaltz: Sounds like your design is broken. What should happen if a malicious user entered a message like `blah blah} {fake user message injection} {blah blah` ?

Comment: The string would come out as  { blah blah } {fake user message injection}{blah blah }. The regex i'm hoping for should still work.

Comment: @edsaltz: How would the computer know that it's not three separate messages?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but checking for balanced round brackets is tricky but **not** impossible

You can try this

```
{[^}]*({[^}{]*})?[^{]*}
      -----------
           |
           |->starting from the center..
```

---

Using `regex` for such problems is not a good choice..

You are better off with your own `parser`...

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanted to do it this way you could combine regex with the `split` function to return an array of values, eg:

```
str = '{ This is {a} test }  { this {is a{ also a } } } test }{ this }  test }';
```

This removes the first and last braces from the string (using the `replace`) then split it based on `} {` (a closing brace followed by zero or more spaces then an opening brace)

```
arr = str.replace(/^\s*\{|\}\s*$/g,'').split(/\}\s*\{/);
```

returns an array:

```
arr = [" This is {a} test ", " this {is a{ also a } } } test ", " this }  test "]
```